# Changing the Javascript hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the `HTML` link which is in Javascript on the `thankyou` page. I even tried changing the HTML links of all the respective pages on the `thankyou` page to `index.html/javascript:goTo(XXXX)` but it is not working.

How will I change the link so that I can link the `thankyou` page to the respective pages?  By the way, both the index and thankyou pages use the same HTML template. The codes are shown here as following:

**index.html**

```
    <div id="preloader"></div>

<div id="menu-wrap">

    <ul class="slimmenu">
        <li> 
            <a href="javascript:goTo('home');">home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:goTo('about');">about us</a>

        </li>
        <li> 
            <a href="javascript:goTo('services');">What We Do</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**thankyou.html**

```
    <div id="preloader"></div>

<div id="menu-wrap"> 

    <ul class="slimmenu">
        <li> 
            <a href="javascript:goTo('home');">home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="index2.html">about us</a>

        </li>
        <li> 
            <a href="index2.html">What We Do</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript function goTo**

```
    function goTo(id){
            var obj = eval("colors."+id);

            $("body").css("background",obj.background);
            $("ul.slimmenu li a").css("color",obj.background);
            if(obj.index > currentIndex){
                $(".active").addClass("off");
                $(".active").transition({
                    x : -100,
                    opacity : 0,
                    zIndex : 0
                },600);

                $("#"+currentId).removeClass("active");

                $("#"+id).addClass("active");
                $("#"+id).transition({
                    perspective: '100px',
                    rotate3d: '1,1,0,90deg'
                },0,function(){
                    $("#"+id).removeClass("off");
                    $("#"+id).transition({
                        rotate3d: '0,0,0,0deg',
                    x : 0,
                        opacity : 1,
                        zIndex : 2
                    },600);
                });
            }else if(obj.index < currentIndex){
                $(".active").addClass("off");
                $(".active").transition({
                    x : 100,
                    opacity : 0,
                    zIndex : 0
                },600);
                $("#"+currentId).removeClass("active");


                $("#"+id).addClass("active");
                $("#"+id).transition({
                    perspective: '100px',
                    rotate3d: '1,1,0,-90deg'
                },0,function(){
                    $("#"+id).removeClass("off");
                    $("#"+id).transition({
                        rotate3d: '0,0,0,0deg',
                    x : 0,
                        opacity : 1,
                        zIndex : 2
                    },600);
                });
            }
            currentIndex = obj.index;
            currentId = id;

        }
```

Comment: Share your `goTo` javascript function

Comment: is it possible that you didn't include the javascript function itself on the thankyou page?

Comment: @mohamedrias I have added it here. Is there any way to link directly? I dont wish to use the redirecting javascript method because I had already used it and I got informed that the redirecting method may not be advised.

Comment: @user1914292 there is, just that I did not add it here. and the function is stored as a standalone js file and linked to the main page.